# Using UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition with CABasicAnimation has weird glitch

Tags: swift, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm implementing custom transition using **CABasicAnimation** and **UIView.animate** both. Also need to implement a custom interactive transition using **UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition** which exactly copies the behavior of the native iOS swipe back. Animation without a back swipe gesture (when I'm pushing and popping by the back arrow) works fine and smoothly. Moreover, swipe back also works smoothly, ***except when the gesture velocity is more than 900***

Gesture Recognition function:

```swift
@objc func handleBackGesture(_ gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard animationTransition != nil else { return }
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            interactionController = TransparentNavigationControllerTransitionInteractor(duration: anumationDuration)
            popViewController(animated: true)

        case .changed:
            guard let view = gesture.view?.superview else { return }
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
            var percentage = translation.x / view.bounds.size.width
            percentage = min(1.0, max(0.0, percentage))
            shouldCompleteTransition = percentage > 0.5
            interactionController?.update(percentage)

        case .cancelled, .failed, .possible:
            if let interactionController = self.interactionController {
                isInteractiveStarted = false
                interactionController.cancel()
            }

        case .ended:
            interactionController?.completionSpeed = 0.999
            let greaterThanMaxVelocity = gesture.velocity(in: view).x > 800
            let canFinish = shouldCompleteTransition || greaterThanMaxVelocity
            canFinish ? interactionController?.finish() : interactionController?.cancel()
            interactionController = nil

        @unknown default: assertionFailure()
        }
    }
```

**UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition** class. Here I'm synchronizing layer animation.

```swift
final class TransparentNavigationControllerTransitionInteractor: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {

    // MARK: - Private Properties

    private var context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
    private var pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = 0
    private let animationDuration: TimeInterval

    // MARK: - Initialization

    init(duration: TimeInterval) {
        self.animationDuration = duration * 0.4 // I dk why but layer duration should be less 
        super.init()
    }

    // MARK: - Public Methods

    override func startInteractiveTransition(_ transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        super.startInteractiveTransition(transitionContext)
        context = transitionContext

        pausedTime = transitionContext.containerView.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        transitionContext.containerView.layer.speed = 0
        transitionContext.containerView.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

    override func finish() {
        restart(isFinishing: true)
        super.finish()
    }

    override func cancel() {
        restart(isFinishing: false)
        super.cancel()
    }

    override func update(_ percentComplete: CGFloat) {
        super.update(percentComplete)
        guard let transitionContext = context else { return }
        let progress = CGFloat(animationDuration) * percentComplete
        transitionContext.containerView.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime + Double(progress)
    }

    // MARK: - Private Methods 

    private func restart(isFinishing: Bool) {
        guard let transitionLayer = context?.containerView.layer else { return }
        transitionLayer.beginTime = transitionLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        transitionLayer.speed = isFinishing ? 1 : -1
    }
}
```

And here is my **Dismissal animation** function in ***UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning*** class

```swift
private func runDismissAnimationFrom(
        _ fromView: UIView,
        to toView: UIView,
        in transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) else { return }
        toView.frame = toView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -fromView.frame.width / 3, dy: 0)

        let toViewFinalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
        let fromViewFinalFrame = fromView.frame.offsetBy(dx: fromView.frame.width, dy: 0)

        // Create mask to hide bottom view with sliding
        let slidingMask = CAShapeLayer()
        let initialMaskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(
            x: fromView.frame.width / 3,
            y: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: toView.frame.height)
        )
        let finalMaskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: toViewFinalFrame)
        slidingMask.path = initialMaskPath.cgPath
        toView.layer.mask = slidingMask
        toView.alpha = 0

        let slidingAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        slidingAnimation.fromValue = initialMaskPath.cgPath
        slidingAnimation.toValue = finalMaskPath.cgPath
        slidingAnimation.timingFunction = .init(name: .linear)
        slidingMask.path = finalMaskPath.cgPath
        slidingMask.add(slidingAnimation, forKey: slidingAnimation.keyPath)

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration,
            delay: 0,
            options: animationOptions,
            animations: {
                fromView.frame = fromViewFinalFrame
                toView.frame = toViewFinalFrame
                toView.alpha = 1
        },
            completion: { _ in
                toView.layer.mask = nil
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
```

I note that glitch occurs only when a swipe has a grand velocity.
Here a video with the result of smooth animation at normal speed and not smooth at high speed - https://youtu.be/1d-kTPlhNvE

***UPD:***
I've already tried to use **UIViewPropertyAnimator** combine with 
**interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating**

But the result is another type of glitching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've **solved** the issue, just change a part of *restart* function:

```swift
        transitionLayer.beginTime = 
transitionLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - transitionLayer.timeOffset
        transitionLayer.speed = 1
```

I don't really understand why, but looks like ***timeOffset*** subtraction works!